# How often should the handshake connect request be called by a websocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket, django-channels

I have an issue (well I think it is an issue) with my websocket trying to do the 'connect -> handshake' thing multiple times. The websocket all works as expected . It is for a generic chat feature. There is nothing that would suggest multiple websockets are open. I am using the Java Script WebSocket object with django + channels back end.

This is what I get server side when I open the web socket and send the first initialisation using js's websocket.send() function. All other request using the websocket will habe handshakes and connects after (more than one). Is this normal?

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41956]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41956]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41958]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41958]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41962]
HTTP GET /messenger/get_chats/ 200 [0.04, 192.168.43.128:41960]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41962]
{"action":"init","data":{"token":"4568dbd702753c32f969fcd3485ba92dbf6aceef"}}
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41966]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41966]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41968]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:41968]
```

After the initial start up and when I send a new chat message I get this for each message (you can probably ignore the http request):

```
HTTP GET /messenger/get_chats/ 200 [0.03, 192.168.43.128:43754]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:43756]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/messenger/ [192.168.43.128:43756]
```

The is no other device connected so this is the only websocket.

Is this normal?

Comment: Notice that you have different port numbers (of source) for each handshake/connect pair. It would indicate that your client side code is actually opening multiple websocket connections.

Comment: Yes!. that is it! Fixed the code. I blame react native :P